# Can I sue Dominos for putting meat on my veg pizza three times

Tags: restaurants

I always buy vegetable pizzas from Dominos. Although I am not vegetarian, I eat vegetarian due to religious restrictions. Once, I found pepperoni on my pizza. And another time I found what looked to be chicken. I believe it to be because my surname reveals that I am a muslim. Unfortunately, my child loves dominos and this specific location is the nearest one available. We always got issues such as an incorrect order or a dry pizza. I complained to corporate for which they gave me coupons for free pizza but even the free pizza was bad. The day that I found the chicken I called the manager and said that I would be opening a case. He said go ahead ,we will be ready. I am tired of this and my poor child can’t even get pizza.

Anyway, I won’t be purchasing Domino’s again from this location but the question I have is: will I be able to sue them? Now before anyone goes of saying that we shouldn’t go suing everything, this is the first business that I’ve seen with such bad customer service!

Comment: I don't think many Americans (if that's where this is) think of Muslims as vegetarian, if anything they only know about the prohibition of pork.

Comment: Do you have a dollar amount in mind for finding meat in your food?  Good luck finding a lawyer to take your case for what is likely at most a hundred dollar claim.  Go to another pizza place.  And stop going to businesses way before you feel you need to sue them.

Comment: @AzorAhai Muslims aren't vegeterian but there is more to halal food than it just being 'not pork'. Just as if you are Orthodox Jew, 'not pork' doesn't mean it's kosher. And certainly expect the TSA to put you on a list if you order a vegeterian airline meal.

Comment: @richardb Please be careful with the term halal and its counterpart haram. Pork product is haram (forbidden) while white bread generally is halal. Halal means allowed.

Comment: @richardb I've ordered plenty of vegetarian meals on airlines and no issues so far, lmao. Are you serious? And my comment was more directed at the chicken bit, i.e. I don't think very many people in the US see a Muslim last name and think "haha I'll put chicken on to mess with them," pepperoni, maybe.

Comment: @Trish I don't know why you think I am confused. I'm not sure how you interpret my sentence as saying anything other than "pork is forbidden but that doesn't mean everything else is allowed"

Comment: @AzorAhai Maybe it isn't actually a thing that happens _yet_. https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/muslim-meals-could-be-used-profile-passengers-airline-tells-authorities